# expression to count field only if another field is distinct in the dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a column in my report that adds up the value of a field depending on that fields value, like this:

```
=COUNT(iif(Fields!isAcceptable.Value > 0, 1, Nothing))
```

However, I need that count to be dependent on the another field called testItemId. Sometimes testItemId, can appear 2 or more times in the dataset, but I need the above count expression to only count once per testItemId. So if the same testItemId appears 4 times, I only want the isAceptable value to be counted once.

I also tried COUNTDISTINCT, but that just gave me a '-1' for each row.

Is there a way to do do this in the expression?

Thanks

Comment: If `TestItemId` is repeated the `isAcceptable` value is repeated too?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!isAcceptable.Value>0,Fields!TestID.Value,Nothing))
```

It will produce this:

[image]

UPDATE:

It says: if the row is acceptable (greater than 0) it will pass `TestID` to the `CountDistinct` function otherwise it will pass nothing (think the row is ommited). `CountDistinct` will get the `TestID` values sum by `1` when a **new** `TestId` value is passed.

> Returns a count of all distinct **non-null** values specified by the
>   expression, evaluated in the context of the given scope.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/dd255245.aspx)

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks,  can you please explain how this works?  I looked up the syntax for CountDistinct, but I couldn't find any examples like yours.

Comment: @999cm999, check my update. Hope it helps you to understand what the expression is doing.